# How to call a function in child in a setInterval from parent?

Tags: reactjs

I have a Monster component, in this component a function is called every 300ms to make it move.

I tried with a setInterval in ComponentDidMount in Monster component but I have many Monsters so the setInterval called for each Monster make the app very slow because if I have 10 monster, I have 10 setinterval.

So I try width a function called in setInterval in parent like that.

Here is my parent Component :

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        Monster.handleMove('EAST')
    }, 300);
}
```

Here is the Monster component :

```
static moveFromWorld(){
    this.handleMove(this.state.direction)
}

handleMove(direction){
   switch(direction){
       case 'WEST':
           return this.attemptMove('WEST')
       case 'EAST':
           return this.attemptMove('EAST')
       case 'NORTH':
           return this.attemptMove('NORTH')
       case 'SOUTH':
           return this.attemptMove('SOUTH')
       default:
    }
}
```

But I have 2 problems :
- TypeError: Cannot read property 'direction' of undefined : if I give parameter
- TypeError: this.handleMove is not a function : if I remove parameter

How to do that ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

After many tests I can get it.

But it shows me that in fact the slow problem is not that.

Each monster dispatch to store it's new position every 300ms.

So it's slow because each 300ms there is 10 dispatch to store.

Is there a solution for this ?

Thanks again